# cmp instruction in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, cmp

I have the instruction of assembly as follows

```
=> 0x00000000004011ed <+53>:  cmp    $0x35,%ecx
   0x00000000004011f0 <+56>:  je     0x4011f7 <phase_5+63>
   0x00000000004011f2 <+58>:  callq  0x40171e <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004011f7 <+63>:  pop    %rbx
   0x00000000004011f8 <+64>:  retq
```

And to my knowledge is comparing 35 to the value in $ecx, so I show
what is in the registers in gdb.

```
(gdb) i r
rax            0x605106 6312198
rbx            0x605100 6312192
rcx            0x23     35
rdx            0xa      10
rsi            0x4      4
rdi            0x605106 6312198
rbp            0x402500 0x402500 <__libc_csu_init>
rsp            0x7fffffffea10 0x7fffffffea10
r8             0x616aa7 6384295
r9             0x7ffff7fc6700 140737353901824
r10            0x7ffff7fc6700 140737353901824
r11            0x246    582
r12            0x400d00 4197632
r13            0x7fffffffeb00 140737488349952
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x4011ed 0x4011ed <phase_5+53>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
gs             0x0      0
```

And it is 35, so the jump instruction should jump to phase_5+63,
and skip the explode_bomb call, But it does not.

```
=> 0x00000000004011f0 <+56>:  je     0x4011f7 <phase_5+63>
   0x00000000004011f2 <+58>:  callq  0x40171e <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004011f7 <+63>:  pop    %rbx
   0x00000000004011f8 <+64>:  retq   
End of assembler dump.

=> 0x00000000004011f2 <+58>:  callq  0x40171e <explode_bomb>
   0x00000000004011f7 <+63>:  pop    %rbx
   0x00000000004011f8 <+64>:  retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

It actually goes to call the explode_bomb function.
So I'm very confused. Thank you.

Comment: `ecx` is `35` in decimal, `0x23` hex. The instruction compares to `0x35` hex which is `53` decimal. Not what you have in `ecx`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Now it works.